# .grep on an JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to use grep to filter a Javascript Object like so:

```
var options = { 
    5: {
        group: "2",
        title: "foo"
    },
    9: {
        group: "1",
        title: "bar"
    }
};

var groups = $.grep(options, function(e){ return e.group == 2 });
```

I'm getting empty results and I'm guessing it's got something to do with the non-sequential keys of the enclosing object. Any ideas how to fix this?

### Update

I tried a couple of different grep methods, including using

```
for (key in option)
```

to grep on option[key] but I couldn't get his to work. In the end I went a different route as shown here:

```
var option_ids = new Array();
for (key in option) {
    if ( option[key]['group'] == 2 ) option_ids.push(option[key]['id']);
}
```

Comment: Don't you need a list/array for grep?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) over an object and expect a sane result. However, you can `grep` over an array, so we just need to get a list of keys with `Object.keys`:

```
$.grep(Object.keys(options), function (k) { return options[k].group == 2; })
//=> ["5"]
```

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks, I see what you've done here and it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

this is a filter function for filtering both arrays and objects :

```
function filter(target, func) {
  if (target instanceof Array) {
    return target.filter(func);
  } else {
    var result = {};
    $.each(Object.keys(target).filter(function (value) {
      return func.call(null, target[value]);
    }), function (i, value) {
      result[value] = target[value];
    });
  }
}
```